# Creating a custom item for QComboBox in Pyside

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qcombobox

I want to create an item for my `QComboBox` that displays a string and 4 pixmaps in a row (the final usage is so that the user can pick from a list of colour schemes).

Can anyone help me customise the `QStandardItem` to get this effect? I thought I could use the rows to do to it but I've not had much luck. This is what I've tried so far...

```
myComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()       

item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item.setRowCount(4)

colour1 = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
colour1 .fill(QtGui.QColor("red"))

colour2 = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
colour2 .fill(QtGui.QColor("blue"))

colour3 = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
colour3 .fill(QtGui.QColor("white"))

childitem1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(QtGui.QIcon(colour1), "1")
childitem2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(QtGui.QIcon(colour2), "2")
childitem3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(QtGui.QIcon(colour3), "3")

item.setChild(0, childitem1)
item.setChild(1, childitem2)
item.setChild(2, childitem3)

myComboBox.model().appendRow(item)
```

But I just get an empty item and none of the children are visible - there's a good chance I've completely misunderstood how this works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [QStandarItemModel](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStandardItemModel.html), append your items to it, and at the end you have to set this model to your combobox with `myComboBox.setModel()`.

Something like this

```
itemModel = QStandardItemModel()

# create your items as you want
itemModel.appendRow(your_items)

myComboBox.setModel(itemModel)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately I'm not quite getting the result I expected. I've done this:

        `itemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("1")
        item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("2")
        item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem("3")
        
        itemModel.appendRow([item1, item2, item3])
                
        myComboBox.setModel(itemModel)`

But the result is a combobox entry with just the first item in it, not "2" and "3" as expected

Comment: I think I've found the problem, the Combobox seems to only display one column at once, rather all 3 of them! I'll keep digging and see if there's a way to show more

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get a sort of half solution by putting a table view into the combo box like this:

```
    itemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

    item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("1")
    item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("2")
    item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem("3")

    itemModel.appendRow([item1, item2, item3])
    myComboBox.setModel(itemModel)

    tv = QtGui.QTableView()
    tv.setModel(itemModel)
    tv.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
    tv.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    tv.resizeColumnsToContents()
    tv.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

    myComboBox.setView(tv)
```

It's a not 100% pretty but it just about does the job! Thanks for the help getting there.